# Using Mongo recommended to store data inside an hashmap

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb

I just recently switch from MySQL to MongoDB, I'm wondering with MySQL I stored the player data inside a hashmap and retrieved name, coins etc; like that so I don't have to constantly query the database to retrieve the data.

Now with MongoDB would I need to do the same thing store the values inside a hashmap and retrieve it the same way I did with MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your requirement. You have migrated to mongodb from mysql, this doesnt means that your reads would be superfast. If there would have been any significant I/O improvement in mongodb, mysql developers would have adopted it as well. MongoDB provide flexibility over mysql and there are some more advantages there. So If your load remains the same, you should have a caching layer before mongodb layer. Both Mysql and mongodb come with in-built caching which caches results on the basis of query just like a hashmap, but rest data is on disk and as mentioned mongodb doesnt have any technical advantage over mysql in terms of I/O. So have a caching layer to avoid excessive querying to db.